# Angular speed and voltage-intensity

Tags: voltage, electromagnetism, generator, coil

I have a square frame with 200 windings rotating in a magnetic field B=0.2T. If I increase the angular speed of rotation of the frame will only the voltage increase? will the electric current also increase?

Comment: (There still is an intensity in the title.)

Answer (score 1):

> will the electric current also increase?

The *load* sets the current, not the source.

Many (but not all) loads, do draw more current when more voltage is applied. With some loads (constant power) the current decreases when the voltage increases.

Without knowing the load, there is no way to know for sure if the current will increase.